# Restore databases from InnoBD files

Tags: mysql, innodb

Hello and good morning/evening/night to anyone reading this. One of our customers lost all data in their server and we had to reinstall a new server completely new.

I have been given the task to restore their 8 MySQL InnoDB databases. **I only have a backup of the /var/lib/mysql directory**, which contains the database directories, the *.ibd* and *.frm* files in them and the ib config files (*ibdata1, ib_logfile...*)

[Content of backup of /var/lib/mysql, the *adesa_* directories are the databases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t38d6.png)

When I copy the databases into the new `/var/lib/mysql` I get an error saying the tables don't exist, so I also need to copy the ibdata1 and ib_logfile0 and 1. However, I get a `ERROR 1524 (HY000): Plugin 'auth_socket' is not loaded` when I try to access the database.

And sometimes mysql service wont start at all

How could I restore the databases, or at least, make a dump into a .sql file?

Comment: Did you replace the same version of MySQL that was being used before the loss

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/98666/is-it-possible-to-restore-a-mysql-database-only-using-files-from-data-directory

Comment: Such questions should now really be asked on the DBA sister site of SO as the question is not about programming, but database admin activities.

Comment: @RiggsFolly that's one of the issues, we don't know what version on MySql they used. Thanks for the link, I've seen that before but I will give it another in-depth read

Comment: @Shadow You are right, I will keep that in mind, thank you

Comment: This may help you identify the version of Mysql that was being used [From another place](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41338/can-i-find-out-what-version-of-mysql-from-the-data-files)